# Password reset laravel 5.7, route is defined

Tags: php, laravel

So I am having some issues with laravel 5.7 and its password reset. (Not sure why Taylor didn't include this in the template when you run `php artisan make:auth`

How ever, consider the following:

```
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest               |
|        | POST     | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest               |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web                     |
|        | POST     | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest               |
|        | POST     | password/reset         | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest               |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest               |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest               |
|        | POST     | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest               |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest               |
```

These are my auth routes, as defined by laravel. No changes, no customizations. So How am I linking to this reset (`password.reset`) route?

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('password.reset', ['token' => app('auth.password.broker')->createToken(Auth::user())]) }}">Reset Password</a>
```

Ok, so whats the issue?

```
NotFoundHttpException {#521 ▼
  -statusCode: 404
  -headers: []
  #message: ""
  #code: 0
  #file: "/Users/*****/Documents/****/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php"
  #line: 179
  trace: {▶}
}
```

Essentially, a 404. When you click the link you are redirected to the 404 page. Which shouldn't happen.

**How am I doing password reset wrong?**

Again this is default everything in a brand new laravel set up. No customizations have been made aside from adding a link for reseting ones password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password reset should be the following link:

```
{{ route('password.request') }}
```

copied from the `login.blade.php`

```
<a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
</a>
```

and the `password.reset` named route is used in the email notification.

Comment: Omg it is in the login blade how did I not see that

Comment: @TheWebs it happens to all of us :) please consider accepting the answer if it helped.